# How do I make my class unselected

Tags: javascript, css, flickr

so I have a set of images pulled in from flickr api and have made it so you can click your favourite pictures and it will save them in local storage so when you refresh it shows them again.

I am just unsure how I would make the images I have selected unselected again.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style media="screen">
            .selected {
                border: 1px solid;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function(){
                var tags='london';
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                window.storage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('images')) || [];
                console.log(window.storage);
                window.cb = function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
                        var image = data.items[i];
                        var classImage = "";
                        if(window.checkimageSelected(image)){
                            classImage = 'selected'
                        }
                        document.getElementById('images').innerHTML += '<img class="'+classImage+'" id="'+i+'" onClick="imageClick(this, '+ i +');" src=' + image.media.m +'/>' ;
                    }
                }

                window.checkimageSelected = function (image) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < window.storage.length; i++) {
                        console.log(window.storage[i].src);
                        console.log(image.media.m);
                        if ((window.storage[i].src ) == image.media.m + '/'){
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                script.src='http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=window.cb&tags='+tags;
                document.head.appendChild(script);
                window.imageClick = function(el, id){
                    el.className += " selected";
                    console.log(el.src);
                    console.log(id);
                    window.storage.push({'id' : id , 'src' : el.src});
                    localStorage.setItem('images', JSON.stringify(window.storage));

                }
            })();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="images">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

here a jsfiddle -- >
https://jsfiddle.net/3qwk8zv0/

```
  (function(){
     function toggleClass(element, className){
      if (!element || !className){
          return;
      }

      var classString = element.className, nameIndex = classString.indexOf(className);
      if (nameIndex == -1) {
          classString += ' ' + className;
      }
      else {
          classString = classString.substr(0, nameIndex) + classString.substr(nameIndex+className.length);
      }
      element.className = classString;
  }


            var tags='london';
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            window.storage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('images')) || [];
            console.log(window.storage);
            window.cb = function(data){
                console.log(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
                    var image = data.items[i];
                    var classImage = "";
                    if(window.checkimageSelected(image)){
                        classImage = 'selected'
                    }
                    document.getElementById('images').innerHTML += '<img class="'+classImage+'" id="'+i+'" onClick="imageClick(this, '+ i +');" src=' + image.media.m +'/>' ;
                }
            }

            window.checkimageSelected = function (image) {
                 var result = window.storage.filter(function(obj){  return obj.src.indexOf(image.media.m)>-1 && obj.isSelected });                    
              return (result && result.length>0);
            }
            script.src='https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=window.cb&tags='+tags;
            document.head.appendChild(script);
            window.imageClick = function(el){
               toggleClass(el,"selected");

                    var currentImage = window.storage.filter(function(obj){  return  el.src == obj.src})[0];
                  if (!currentImage) {
                  currentImage = {'src' : el.src};
                  window.storage.push(currentImage);
                  }
                       if (el.className.indexOf('selected')==-1){
                 currentImage.isSelected = false;
                 }else{
                          currentImage.isSelected = true;
                 }
                localStorage.setItem('images', JSON.stringify(window.storage));

            }
        })();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works but I have one more problem, when an image is unselected after previously being selected when the page is refreshed it shows it as selected again, how would I store this in local storage?

Comment: by the way do you know of any javascript tests I could add for this?